# making Bouncing Ball to stop after it looses energy

Tags: javascript

I have written an update function to bounce a ball horizontally in a canvas, but I need to modify it to top after it looses energy and becomes idle.

```
   function update(){
    x = 150;
    y = 50;
    bounceFactor = 0.7;
    dx = parseInt(document.getElementById("vx").value, 10); 
    dy = parseInt(document.getElementById("vy").value, 10); 

    clearCanvas();
    draw();

    y += vy;

   vy += gravity;

  if(y + radius > H) {

       //   ball.y = H - ball.radius;
        ball.vy *= -bounceFactor;

    }
}
```

Comment: Make a fiddle for more clearence

Comment: http://www.htmlbestcodes.com/Bouncing_ball.htm     try this hope it will help you

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but i want to stop the ball completely after few bounces, for more details (http://jsfiddle.net/ravikiran6763/ct7x3nts/)